# NSMutableArray addObject not inserting at the end of array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have the code below that iterate on every book on my bookObjects array, my problem is addObject is inserting/adding my aBook object on random index instead of adding it at the end of self.books

i just want it to follow the order of the books in bookObjects, no specific order or sorting.

books is an NSMutableArray

```
NSArray *bookObjects = [element childrenNamed:@"books"];

int i = 0;
for(SMXMLElement *child in bookObjects)
{
    NSString *isbn = [child valueWithPath:@"isbn"]; 
    NVBook *aBook = [self getBookByISBN:isbn];
    if(nil == aBook)
    {
        aBook = [NVBook insertBookInContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        aBook.isbn = isbn;

        [self.books addObject:aBook];
    }

    aBook.indexInList = i++;
    [aBook updateContentWithElement:child];
}
```

additional code

```
+ (NVBook *)insertBookInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
}


- (NVBook *)getBookByISBN:(NSString *)aISBN
{
    NVBook *aBook = nil;

    for(NVBook *book in self.books)
    {
        if([book.isbn isEqual:aISBN])
        {
            aBook = book;
            break;
        }
    }

    return aBook;
}
```

Comment: [addObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is defined to add at the end of the array. I would suggest adding a `NSLog(@"%@", aBook);` inside your loop to verify that it is called in the order you expect.

Comment: addObject will add the book to the end of the array, something else must be changing the order. I'm guessing that something is changing bookObjects rather than books.

Comment: @rdelmar bookObjects is consistent, it has the same order everytime i load it, at the end of loop whenever i do a "po self.books" on my debugger, the order are all messed up. my bookObjects from XML are all correct.

Comment: @James i do "po aBook" on debugger on each item on the loop and its in correct order

Comment: What does insertBookInContext: do? It's hard to tell what's going on without knowing what some of your methods do.

Comment: @rdelmar added the code for insertBookInContext

Comment: That doesn't help much, unfortunately. The thing I can't figure out is what books in bookObjects are nil? It seems like books will only contain newly created books since you only get into that if clause if getBooksByISBN returns nil. Without knowing your data structure it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @rdelmar thank you for replying. getBookByISBN will make it sure that i will only add the new book if it doesn't exist yet.